# Add Up All Mysql Values PHP

Tags: php, mysql, download

Hey, I have a tables called downloads, and in that table it stores the total amount of downloads for each day, so like

```
downloads  date
586  07-16-2010
906  07-17-2010
1019  07-18-2010
287  07-19-2010
15   07-20-2010
639  07-21-2010
337  07-22-2010
```

How could I retrieve the total number of downloads, so add them all up from every single day :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you believe it's as simple as

```
select sum(downloads) as total_downloads
  from downloads
```

**EDIT**

```
$query = 'select sum(downloads) as total_downloads from downloads';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$total_downloads = $row['total_downloads'];
```

Comment: it's giving me Resource id #32  any ideas?  <-- nvm fixed that with mysql_fetch_row

Comment: of course you should add your where statement to limit it to the day to today ... more info on date time functions at http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments#conditionalcomments__tbl_conditional-comments_operators

Comment: of course it's giving you a resource id! it's returning the query handle not the result

$res = mysql_query('select sum(downloads) as total_downloads from downloads'); 

$total_count= mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_BOTH); 

more info at php.org

Comment: @Belgin PHP's mysql_query() returns a resource comprising one or more rows of data. You need to fetch the first row (using a function like mysql_fetch_assoc()) and then get the value of total_downloads returned in the associative array returned by that